# Get or set env variable in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, environment-variables, yaml, docker-compose

I have got a `docker-compose.yml` file and there I define:

```
extra_hosts:
- "localhost:${MY_MACHINE_IP}"
```

It works if I define MY_MACHINE_IP as environment var earlier.

What I want to achieve is to perform action like:

```
extra_hosts:
- "localhost:<get MY_MACHINE_IP from env if it exists, if not set MY_MACHINE_IP env variable with value <docker-machine-ip>>"
```

In other words: I want to define it in extra_hosts section, if MY_MACHINE_IP is already specified, get it, if not - set this env. variable with value = my docker machine ip.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in according to docker documentation

```
docker-compose run SERVICE env
```

So i think the variables are not global as you may think. You have to pass them as parameters. 
Read [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/).

Comment: can you give me an example according to my question? How it will looks like? Because I think I don't fully understand you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the env i ment this: "MY_MACHINE_IP=0.0.0.0" you can read more here. There is more options if you use docker-compsoe UP - not RUN https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `ruamel.dcw` for that (`dcw` for Docker Compose Wrapper, disclaimer: I am the author of that package). It allows you to create a section with key `user-data` in your `docker-compose.yaml` file, which is stripped out before handing the file to the normal `docker-compose`. That section can look like:

```
user-data:
  author: Your Name <your-name@youremail.com>
  description: container for postfix/submission
  env-defaults:
    PORT: 587    # override during development
    NAME: submission
    DOCKER_BASE: /data0/DATA
```

and then you can use `{PORT}`, `{NAME}` and `{DOCKER_BASE}` in the rest of the file, with the option of overriding these default values with environment variables.

The utility also write out a file `.dcw_env_vars.inc` which you can copy into your container and source to get the appropriate values into scripts you `RUN` from within the `Dockerfile`

Comment: for a few "specials" it is possible to do `HOST_IP: <hostip` to set the (external) ip of the host.